# Append Maybe to List in Elm

Tags: list, elm, option-type

I have a `List a` and a `Maybe a`. I want to append the maybe value if it is `Just a` but do nothing if it is `Nothing`.

This is what I am currently using:

```
aList ++ case maybeValue of
           Just value ->
             [ value ]
           Nothing ->
             []
```

Is there a better (more idiomatic) way of doing this?

Note that prepending is fine too if there is a cleaner way of doing that instead. The list order does not matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use `Maybe.map List.singleton yourMaybe |> Maybe.withDefault []`.

Here you have a complete example:

```
appendMaybe : List a -> Maybe a -> List a
appendMaybe list maybe =
    Maybe.map List.singleton maybe
        |> Maybe.withDefault []
        |> (++) list
```

You can try it on [Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/3Yv3kYS7KHfa1/1)

Comment: That works. I'm just not sure that it is better than using the case-of. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't think it is better, I think it is just more idiomatic. Let's see if people give some other responses

Answer (score 6):

From Chad's suggestion that prepending is cheaper:

```
prependMaybe : List a -> Maybe a -> List a
prependMaybe list maybe =
   case maybe of
           Just value ->
             value :: list
           Nothing ->
             list
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going for conciseness, you could use [`Maybe.Extra.unwrap`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/maybe-extra/4.0.0/Maybe-Extra#unwrap) from the `elm-community/maybe-extra` package:

```elm
import Maybe.Extra exposing (unwrap)

consMaybe : List a -> Maybe a -> List a            
consMaybe list =
    unwrap list (flip (::) list)

appendMaybe : List a -> Maybe a -> List a            
appendMaybe list =
    unwrap list ((++) list << List.singleton)
```

If you really want to go crazy, you can create your own infix operators:

```elm
infixr 5 ::?
(::?) = flip consMaybe

infixr 5 ++?
(++?) = appendMaybe
```

This allows the following:

```elm
Nothing ::? [2, 3, 4] == [2, 3, 4]
Just 1  ::? [2, 3, 4] == [1, 2, 3, 4]

[2, 3, 4] ++? Nothing == [2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4] ++? Just 5  == [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now, whether the infix versions are idiomatic Elm, that's up for debate. If it's something you use a lot, perhaps it's worth it, but most Elm guides urge you to avoid infix operators because they hinder discoverability.

In the end, your original example has the benefit of being readable and probably more readily understandable, since fewer people will be familiar with `unwrap`. The only suggestion would be that if order truly doesn't matter, then prepending an item to a list is going to be faster than concatenating lists.